# Open a pdf file in a file system in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pdf

My Rails app is generating a PDF file in a file system. 
When the user clicks "Preview" button in the front-end which is in Angular, it generates a PDF file and returns path.

```
def renderPDF()
 # PDF render codes
 STORAGE_PATH = 'public/rendered'
 return "#{STORAGE_PATH}/example.pdf"
end
```

In my front-end, I would like to open this PDF when the `Preview` button is clicked. How would I show the PDF file on the browser?

Comment: Is it okay if the pdf is opened in a new tab/widow?

Comment: @agustaf Yes. But I would also be down to know how to open the PDF in same tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display a PDF in ROR (Ruby)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500451/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-in-ror-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

```
def renderPDF
  storage_path = 'public/rendered'
  send_file("#{storage_path}/example.pdf", :filename => 'your_document.pdf', :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'application/pdf')
end
```

Comment: it seems like it's not opening pdf file. Method runs fine tho.

Comment: Ok, so I just tried it and the problem, for me, is that all caps variable are interpreted as constants. See the edit, STORAGE_PATH is changed to storage_path.

Comment: I'm wondering why `example.pdf` and `your_document.pdf` are different. Am I not supposed to put `example.pdf` for `filename`? And i tried it but it doesn't do anything. Not sure why.

Comment: If you wanted, but it doesn't matter. If the user downloads the file it will show  the filename you choose here which you may or may not want to be different. If you wanted them to be the same you could just exclude filename. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

Comment: Gotcha. Any guess why it's not opening the pdf tho? I confirm that the function send_file runs in the console but it doesn't do anything in the browser.

Comment: Did you already change your variable to not all caps? http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html

Comment: Yes, I did change everything.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird, can you add what your server says to your question?