# How to embed PDF in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to Rails development and I can't understand how to embed a PDF file in the browser. I already looked for others questions on the same subject like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500451/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-in-ror-ruby) and I'm dumbfounded. Already changed all the answer said but it just doesn't work.

This is my function

```
# create pdf function
  def pdf
    menu_pdf = File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/files/menulq2.pdf')
    send_file(menu_pdf, filename: 'menulq2.pdf.pdf', disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/pdf')
  end
```

And now I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The SO Answer you link to is about downloading/sending PDF files to/from your server. You needed to scroll down farther to read about displaying PDFs within your HTML views.

There's no reason to have a `SomeModel#pdf` method in your Model unless each record links to a specific PDF (e.g. if the model were `Restaurant` and you had a PDF menu for each `restaurant`.

---

You can just use an HTML [`embed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) tag:

`<embed src="http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375"  type="application/pdf">`

As long as the path for 'app/assets/files' is in the [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)
, you can use [`asset_path`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) helper:

```
<embed src="<%= asset_path('menulq2.pdf') %>" width="500" height="375" 
 type="application/pdf">
```

The benefit here is if your assets are getting precompiled, the filename might be changed from `menulq2.pdf` to something like `menulq2-60aa4fdc5cea14baf5400fba1abf4f2a46a5166bad4772b1effe341570f07de9.pdf`, in which case, you as the developer, don't actually know what the PDF's filename actually is.

So the `asset_path` helper allows you to specify the simple filename and not worry about what asset compliation might have done to the name.

---

If that's too fiddly, or you know this asset isn't getting precompiled, you can hard-code it into the HTML:

```
<embed src="/assets/files/menulq2.pdf" width="500" height="375" 
 type="application/pdf">
```

To hard-code the URL you need to make sure you are serving static files by setting this to `true` in your environment files (`/config/environments/*.rb`):

For Rails 4: `config.serve_static_files = true`

For Rails 5+: `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`